# Titanium load Facebook profile picture integration doesn't work

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium, appcelerator

I'm looking for a way to integrate the Facebook profile picture in my Titanium App. I was googling an then i've tried this one:

```
var imageAvatar = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image: "http://graph.facebook.com/"+FacebookUID+"/picture",
            left:10, top:5,
            width:50, height:50
          });
```

But this doesn't work, it wont show me the profile picture of the persons UID.

Can anybody help me ? Thank you very much!

Edit #1: I've also tried it with HTML, it works fine! And the UID isn't empty, so thats not the problem.

Edit #2 (more code):

```
var tableData = [];

    for(var i=1; i < json.length; i++) {
        alert(i+' - GAME #'+json[i].GameId);
        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
            className:'forumEvent', // used to improve table performance
            rowIndex:i, // custom property, useful for determining the row during events
            height:110
          });
        var imageAvatar = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image: "http://graph.facebook.com/"+Ti.App.fb.uid+"/picture",
            left:10, top:5,
            width:50, height:50
          });
          row.add(imageAvatar);
          var labelUserName = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            color:'#576996',
            font:{fontFamily:'Arial', fontSize:defaultFontSize+6, fontWeight:'bold'},
            text:'Fred Smith ' + i,
            left:70, top: 6,
            width:200, height: 30
          });
          row.add(labelUserName);
        var labelDetails = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            color:'#222',
            font:{fontFamily:'Impact', fontSize:defaultFontSize+2, fontWeight:'normal'},
            text:'Replied to post with id 1234.',
            left:70, top:44,
            width:360
          });
          row.add(labelDetails);
          tableData.push(row);
    }

    Ti.App.multi_tableView.data = tableData;
```

//Another File

```
Ti.App.multi_tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
top: 60,
bottom: 80
});
```

Comment: Can you show some more code ? if i try your basic example it works.

Comment: I've added more code =)

Comment: thx, can you give the imageView a background color so you can be sure it is visible ?

Comment: Done ;) i can just see the background color. I've also tried another image url, first with an manuell integratet facebook uid, that doesn't work, then i've tried it with just an simple image url, that works fine. Maybe you need to know that this "for" action is in a json request

Comment: So you tried it with a known id hardcoded like this: http://graph.facebook.com/100005647326891/picture and that does not work but another image hosted somewhere else does ? Does it work when you add a facebook image directly to your app outside the for loop / ajax request ?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work, same result like in the loop/ajax request. Just a red background color, no image. Wether its a variable or a hardcoded ... i've tried it with a testaccount-id: 1378163649155341

Comment: And images from other servers do work ? so your connection is good ? Anthing else that could help in the logs maby ?

Comment: Yes, images from another server works fine. Nope, nothing in the logs. Maybe i will download the images to my server when the user uses the facebook login and then i can select the image right at my server ... but thats not solution i am looking for.

Comment: alright well it seems the request to Facebook is blocked or not processed well, but can't help you any further because it is working here i am sorry

Comment: no problem, thank you for your time! i will try to download the pictures direct to my server ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refer below link for more details.

And per this link you need to add version number after host api url like..

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/{user-id}/picture

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture

This works for me.